# A measure of a group's commutativity

Tags: group-theory, terminology, definition, abelian-groups, group-presentation

Let $G$ be a finitely presented group on and let $ma(G) = n$ be the minimum of $\left| K \right|$ ($K \subseteq G$) over all group presentations $G \cong F\{A\} / H$ such that $G / {H \vee [K, K]}$ is commutative.

If $ma(G) = 0$ then $G$ is abelian and if $G = F\{A\}$ then $ma(G) = \left|A\right|$.

Thus $ma$ measures the the numbers of 'steps' $G$ is away from being commutative.

Is this construction useful?  Does it have a name?

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance here. What do you mean by $F\{ A\}$?

Comment: Do you mean, say, the free group over the set $A$?

Comment: Yes, the free group over the set A.

Comment: I thought so, @ThoralfSkolem. When I think about measuring commutativity, by the way, I'm reminded of Lie algebras. It might be worth adding the `lie-algebras` tag.